# Not able to run simple babel from src folder to dist

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, babeljs, glob

I use the following code for babel transpile of code.
My app is built like following

```
-src
 -- bin
   ---www
 -- routes
   ---index1.js
   ---index2.js
 -- config.json
-package.json
```

Now I want that all this file will be transpiled to the **dist** folder

I use the following gulp

```
gulp.task('es6', () => {
    return gulp.src(['src/**/*.js','./src/**/www','./src/**/*.json'])
        .pipe(babel({
            presets: ['es2015']
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});
```

This create new dist of dist like following but without the config.json file,why ?

```
-dist
 -- bin
   ---www
 -- routes
   ---index1.js
   ---index2.js
```

and when I run the gulp file I got error 
Cannot find module `'../config.json'` ,any idea how to solve it ?

I struggle with it almost 3 days, I think I miss something basic here...:( 
This is the project example ,you can do npm install and run gulp to see the error...

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B8fd7J9aXGXaQng1ZFJkU2Z4OUk

Comment: Does the file get copied over if you don't pipe it through Babel? Since JSON isn't valid JS, I'd probably have assumed Babel would throw an error on that file.

Comment: what do you mean? should I copy it with other gulp task  ?

Comment: @loganfsmyth when I copy it with with gulp copy its working ok, so why is that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download and it seems only an issue with babel-gulp which doesn't recognize the .json

edited like this and it works

```
gulp.task('es6', () => {
    return gulp.src(['./src/**/*.js','./src/**/www'])
        .pipe(babel({
            presets: ['es2015']
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});

gulp.task('json', () => {
    return gulp.src(['./src/*.json'])
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'))
})
```

and then

```
gulp.task('default', [ 'es6', 'json', 'nodemon'], () => {
    console.log("Done");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
'./src/**/*.json'
```

but your config file is a direct child of src, so you should do:

```
'./src/*.json'
```

Comment: Thanks I tried it but I got the same issue ? did you try to download the app ? does it works for you?